# Stored procedure in SQL Server which takes table-valued parameter and insert which does not exists and returns which exists

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure which is going to take a table valued parameter as input parameter and will insert if all the row in provided parameter is unique and does not exists in the table `User` and one which already exists will be returned as output as `Duplicate`

Table **User**

```
    ╔════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════╦════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦══════════════╗
    ║ id ║        DateField        ║  registrationno  ║ firstname ║ middlename ║ lastname ║ gender ║    dob     ║ maritalstatus ║  mobileno  ║ landlineno ║   emailid    ║
    ╠════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬═══════════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════╬════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬══════════════╣
    ║  1 ║ 2015-10-16 16:24:27.460 ║ U/10/2015/000001 ║ John      ║ NULL       ║ Doe      ║      1 ║ 1990-10-09 ║             1 ║ 1234567890 ║ 1234567890 ║ jd@gmail.com ║
    ║  2 ║ 2015-10-16 16:24:27.460 ║ U/10/2015/000002 ║ Bean      ║ NULL       ║ Bean     ║      1 ║ 1986-18-12 ║             1 ║ 9874561230 ║ 9874561230 ║ bb@gmail.com ║
    ║  3 ║ 2015-10-16 16:24:27.460 ║ U/10/2015/000003 ║ Jennifer  ║ NULL       ║ Lopez    ║      2 ║ 1980-09-16 ║             1 ║ 9985632147 ║ 9985632147 ║ jl@gmail.com ║
    ║  4 ║ 2015-10-16 16:24:27.460 ║ U/10/2015/000004 ║ Maria     ║ NULL       ║ Stewart  ║      2 ║ 2000-10-15 ║             1 ║ 7458612390 ║ 7458612390 ║ ms@gmail.com ║
    ╚════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════╩════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩══════════════╝
```

Table Type `UserTableType`

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UserTableType] AS TABLE
(
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MiddleName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Lastname] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Gender] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NULL,
    [MaritalStatus] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [MobileNo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LandlineNo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [EmailId] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
GO
```

The procedure as far I had written:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspManageUser] 
        @UserTableType dbo.User READONLY
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @countI INT , @countU INT, @countT INT

        SELECT @countI = count(temp.MobileNo) 
        FROM 
            (SELECT 
                    VPM.FirstName, VPM.MiddleName, VPM.LastName, 
                    CASE VPM.Gender 
                    WHEN 'Male' THEN '1' 
                    WHEN 'Female' THEN 'G2' 
                    END AS [Gender], 
                    getdate() as 'DOB', 
                    CASE VPM.MaritalStatus 
                    WHEN 'Single' THEN 1 
                    END as 'MaritalStatus', 
                    VPM.MobileNo, VPM.LandlineNo, 
                    VPM.EmailId, VPM.Occupation, 
                    VPM.Address1, VPM.Address2, VPM.City, VPM.Pincode
                FROM 
                    @UserTableType AS VPM
                LEFT JOIN 
                    User AS DPM ON DPM.MobileNo = VPM.MobileNo AND VPM.EmailId = DPM.EmailId) temp

        SET @countT= @countI    
        Select @countT

        INSERT INTO 
            dbo.[User](DateField, FirstName,  MiddleName,  LastName,  Gender, dob,   MaritalStatus,  MobileNo, LandlineNo,  EmailId)
        SELECT 
            Getdate(), 
            VPM.FirstName, 
            VPM.MiddleName, 
            VPM.LastName, 
        CASE 
            VPM.Gender  when 'Male'   then 'GE001' 
                        when 'Female' then 'GE002' END,
            getdate(),
        CASE 
            VPM.MaritalStatus when 'Single' then 1 end,
            VPM.MobileNo,
            VPM.LandlineNo,
            VPM.EmailId,
            VPM.Occupation,
            VPM.Address1,
            VPM.Address2,
            VPM.City,
            VPM.Pincode
        FROM
            @UserTableType AS VPM
        LEFT JOIN 
            [User] AS DPM ON DPM.MobileNo = VPM.MobileNo AND VPM.EmailId = DPM.EmailId

        RETURN 1

    END TRY

BEGIN CATCH 
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
END
```

What I want is that a stored procedure in which I read the data from `UserTableType` parameter and if there is a duplicate which i will check on basis of `User.MobileNo` and `User.EmailId` because they are the unique field in the `User` table and if no record exists against the given `User.MobileNo` and `User.EmailId` it will be inserted else if record exists for `User.MobileNo` and `User.EmailId` then a return output will be the resultset which already exists in `User` table

How to go ahead in this?

Comment: So what is your actual problem, in addition to just writing the code?

Comment: my problem is i am not getting it worked kindly review the code and help if possible.

Comment: You do understand that Stack Overflow is for questions, not debugging problems with your code?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess what you need, but here is some (pseudo)code that you might be after.

Return rows that exists already:

```
select * from @UserTableType VPM
where exists (
  select 1 from User DPM
  where DPM.MobileNo = VPM.MobileNo AND VPM.EmailId = DPM.EmailId
)
```

Insert rows that don't exist:

```
insert into User ("list of columns")
select "list of columns" from @UserTableType VPM
where not exists (select 1 from User DPM
  where DPM.MobileNo = VPM.MobileNo AND VPM.EmailId = DPM.EmailId
)
```